# ¿Por qué perdí un punto al votar negativamente una respuesta?

Tags: soporte, votos, reputación, votos-negativos

Tengo entendido que los puntos negativos se dan cuando tu respuesta está baja o mala o comentarios, etc. Sin embargo, ¿por qué yo obtuve un punto negativo cuando solo vote como mala una respuesta?

Comment: Revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: @Rubén gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como bien apunta Rubén en los comentarios, el privilegio [Votar negativo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) tiene este comportamiento:

> ¿Qué sucede cuando voto negativo?
>
> - Los votos negativos quitan **2** de reputación al dueño de la publicación.
> - Los votos negativos en las *respuestas* te quitan **1** de reputación a ti, el votante.
> - Los votos negativos en las *preguntas* son **libres**. ([*¿Por qué?*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/))

Comment: eso es lo que no entiendo osea yo vote negativo porque considero que la pregunta esta mal y deberian mejorarla

Comment: las reglas indican que tu pierdes también un punto @simon

Comment: entonces no es buena idea dar voto negativo a la preguntas "malas"? porque yo pierdo puntos? entonces cual seria mi recompensa por ayudar a la limpieza del sitio? (no me importan los puntos pero solo es una duda por si otro usuario se pregunta lo mismo)

Comment: tu recompensa? ninguna básicamente solo das a conocer con un comentario el por que esta mal esa respuesta y si lo deseas votas negativo

Comment: @simon tu recompensa es que tu buen hacer se extienda y el día que necesites buscar una respuesta a tus dudas te encuentres con que otras almas caritativas y expertas en el tema votaron a favor lo bueno y en contra lo malo, por lo que será más fácil saber cuál es la solución buena a tu problema : )

Comment: @simon *«entonces no es buena idea dar voto negativo a la preguntas "malas"?»* En las preguntas no te quitan puntos, solo en las respuestas

Comment: Actualizo la respuesta ahora que la documentación ya está correcta (https://github.com/g3rv4/help-pages/pull/30) ¡Gracias @g3rv4 por aceptarlo tan rápido!

Comment: En general, cuando votas una respuesta negativamente, es porque sabes cuál es la respuesta correcta. Puedes dar una buena respuesta, y votar negativo otra para dejar clara tu opinión. Si tu respuesta es buena, tendrás enseguida 10 puntos extras que compensarán con creces el negativo.

Comment: Otro dato importante: Si una mala respuesta es borrada, recuperas tus puntos

Comment: De la ayuda: `Cuando votas negativo, estás empujando esa publicación hacia abajo en la página, así que será vista por menos gente. Votar negativo en las publicaciones no es algo que queramos que tomes a la ligera, por lo que no es gratuito.`

Comment: @shadow a mi no me importan los puntos ni recomenpensa solo me importa encortar la solucion y que la comunidad  sepa que yo aporto mi granito de arena para mejorar la respuesta y pregunta :p

Comment: si no te importan los puntos, entonces cual es el problema de perder 1 @simon ? por otro lado la comunidad no debe ser tu foco de atención para que ayudes por que entonces indica que buscas la aprobación y reconocimiento y por ahi no va el asunto, ahi suena un poco a un ego alto amigo eso de querer que la comunidad sepa que tu aportaste

Comment: @shadow que? ajaj no busco ninguna aprobacion o reconocimiento :) yo me refiero :) soy uno mas que intenta ayudar y mejorar la comunidad para que sea una fuente de conocimiento para los  demas y   evitar crear otro yahoo ask aqui :p y porque pregunto esto? cree la pregunte solo por si otro usuario tuviera la misma duda(alguien nuevo) y evitar crear preguntas duplicadas en el meta de español

Answer (score 4):

A partir de conseguir 125 puntos de reputación se puede votar negativo a respuestas que así lo amerite.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Pierdes un punto de tu reputación al votar negativo a una respuesta sin embargo conservas tus puntos cuando votas negativo en una pregunta

https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

¿Por qué ocurre esto?

Así como por día tenemos un límite de votos positivos y negativos como una medida de control, también perdemos un punto de nuestra reputación al votar negativo a respuestas(y esto es mi punto de vista) para tener en control dicha acción.

Si lo anterior no existiera, usuarios mal intencionados con una conducta de voto serial se la pasarían calificando negativas a todas las respuestas.

Vuelvo al punto inicial, si una persona se la pasa votando por ejemplo negativo a respuestas y rebasa el límite de los 125 puntos, quedará imposibilitada para seguir haciendolo, con lo cual se debe asumir que votas negativo a una respuesta cuando así sea necesario nadamas

Comment: Sí, bien apuntado. Yo creo que es esencialmente para minimizar el impacto del voto negativo táctico, es decir, el que hay gente que hace a las respuestas "competidoras". Si no, también se aplicaría el descuento de puntos al voto de preguntas.